# jq truncates ENV variable after whitespace

Tags: json, bash, jq

Trying to write a bash script that replaces values in a JSON file we are running into issues with Environment Variables that contain whitespaces.

Given an original JSON file.

```
{
  "version": "base",
  "myValue": "to be changed",
  "channelId": 0
}
```

We want to run a command to update some variables in it, so that after we run:

```
CHANNEL_ID=1701 MY_VALUE="new value" ./test.sh
```

The JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "version": "base",
  "myValue": "new value",
  "channelId": 1701
}
```

Our script is currently at something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $MY_VALUE
echo $CHANNEL_ID

function replaceValue {
  if [ -z $2 ]; then echo "Skipping $1"; else jq --argjson newValue \"${2}\" '. | ."'${1}'" = $newValue' build/config.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json build/config.json; fi
}

replaceValue channelId ${CHANNEL_ID}
replaceValue myValue ${MY_VALUE}
```

In the above all values are replaced by string and strings are getting truncated at whitespace. We keep alternating between this issue and a version of the code where substitutions just stop working entirely.

This is surely an issue with expansions but we would love to figure out, how we can:
- Replace values in the JSON with both strings and values.
- Use whitespaces in the strings we pass to our script.

Comment: `newValue \"${2}\"` why? Qoute variables with `"` not with `\"`. Why `--argjson` and not `--arg`?

Comment: @KamilCuk: You don't need that, you can directly import env variables in `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass variables with `--arg`. Do:

```
jq --arg key "$1" --arg value "$2" '.[$key] = $value'
```

Notes:

- `#!/bin/sh` indicates that this is *posix shell* script, not bash. Use `#!/bin/bash` in bash scripts.
- `function replaceValue {` is something from ksh shell. Prefer `replaceValue() {` to declare functions. [Bash obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).
- Use newlines in your script to make it readable.
- `--argjson` passes a *json formatted* argument, not a string. Use `--arg` for that.
- `\"${2}\"` doesn't quote `$2` expansion - it only appends and suffixes the string with `"`. Because the expansion is not qouted, word splitting **is** performed, which causes your input to be split on whitespaces when creating arguments for `jq`.
- Remember to quote variable expansions.
- Use http://shellcheck.net to check your scripts.
- `. |` means nothing in `jq`, it's like `echo $(echo $(echo)))`. You could `jq '. | . | . | . | . | .'` do it infinite number of times - it passes the same thing. Just write the thing you want to do.

Do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$MY_VALUE"
echo "$CHANNEL_ID"

replaceValue() {
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
         echo "Skipping $1"
    else
        jq --arg key "$1" --arg value "$2" '.[$key] = $value' build/config.json > tmp.json &&
        mv tmp.json build/config.json
   fi
}

replaceValue channelId "${CHANNEL_ID}"
replaceValue myValue "${MY_VALUE}"
```

@edit Replaced `."\($key)"` with easier `.[$key]`

Comment: Many good points, but `.[$key]` is easier on the eyes and fingers than `."\($key)"` and is also more robust in that it is supported by jq 1.3.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I learned a lot today.

Comment: Although now all value end up as strings in my JSON file. I could fix it by running something like the line below on each value I want to be a number but just wondering if there is a better solution?
`jq '.channelId |= tonumber' build/config.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json build/config.json`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to mess with `--arg` or `--argjson` to import the environment variables into `jq`'s context. It can very well read the environment on its own. You don't need a script separately, just set the values along with the invocation of `jq`

```
CHANNEL_ID=1701 MY_VALUE="new value" \
     jq '{"version": "base", myValue: env.MY_VALUE, channelId: env.CHANNEL_ID}' build/config.json
```

Note that in the case above, the variables need *not* be exported globally but just locally to the `jq` command. This allows you to not export multiple variables into the shell and pollute the environment, but just the ones needed for `jq` to construct the desired JSON.

To make the changes back to the original file, do `> tmp.json && mv tmp.json build/config.json` or more clearly download the [sponge(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) utility from [moreutils](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/moreutils) package. If present, you can pipe the output of `jq` as

```
| sponge build/config.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I think this solution sadly won't work for my case as variables might not be defined. Trying to achieve an overwriting of defaults here. And After a quick try the above code sets unspecified variables to null.
Will look into sponge though.

Answer (score -2):

jq allows you to build new objects:

```
MY_VALUE=foo;
CHANNEL_ID=4
echo '{
  "version": "base",
  "myValue": "to be changed",
  "channelId": 0
}' | jq ". | {\"version\": .version, \"myValue\": \"$MY_VALUE\", \"channelId\": $CHANNEL_ID}"
```

The `.` selects the whole input, and inputs that (`|`) to the construction of a new object (marked by `{}`). For version is selects `.version` from the input, but you can set your own values for the other two. We use double quotes to allow the Bash variable expansion, which means escaping the double quotes in the JSON.

You'll need to adapt my snippet above to scriptify it.

Comment: (1) In jq, `{"version": .version}` can be abbreviated to just `{version}`. (2) As pointed out in another answer, the initial `.|` here is pointless. (3) Using the shell's string interpolation is usually unwise, mainly because it's unsafe, but also because using double-quotes to quote the jq program requires double-quotes within the program to be escaped on the command-line.